# while-loop and if-statement do different command if condition is met

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Inside `file.txt`

```
chicken sheep cow  
tomato cucumber  
banana
```

Without `if` statement

```
while read -r column1 column2 column3; do  
    command  
done < file.txt
```

Using `if` statement, how to if the line has three columns, it do `command1`, if it has two columns, do `command2` and if only has one column, it do `command3`?

Comment: (What if there are more than three? That `read` would concatenate the fourth and so on with the third one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or **other approach** with smallest difference of your example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r column1 column2 column3; do
        if [ -z "$column2" ] ; then
                printf '%s\n' "Only first column has data"
        elif [ -z "$column3" ]; then
                printf '%s\n' "Only first and second columns has data"
        elif [ -n "$column3" ]; then
                printf '%s\n' "All three columns has data"
        fi
done < file.txt
```

Output will be:

```
All three columns has data
Only first and second columns has data
Only first column has data
```

**Notes**:

In your example first and second lines contains several spaces at the end, but by default `read` removes all leading and trailing space characters.

If your input contains more than 3 columns, all data in third column and further will placed in `column3`

See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: You need to quote the variables in the tests: `[ -n "$var" ]` etc. With `-z` it works without the quotes here, slightly accidentally, since if `$var` is empty in `[ -z $var ]`, the expansion is just `[ -z ]` which just tests if `-z` is a nonempty string. The one with `-n`, however, always gives a true result. (Of course whitespace and glob characters in the variable also cause a mess if the vars are unquoted.)

Comment: @ilkkachu, thx. It's fair remark, answer was changed

Answer (score 1):

You may read each line into array with `read -ra`, then, check the array size:

```
fmt="Number of fields: %s. The last one: %s\n"
while read -ra items; do 
    if [ ${#items[*]} == 3 ]; then 
        printf "$fmt" ${#items[*]} ${items[-1]}
    elif [ ${#items[*]} == 2 ]; then 
        printf "$fmt" ${#items[*]} ${items[-1]}
    elif [ ${#items[*]} == 1 ]; then
        printf "$fmt" ${#items[*]} ${items[-1]}
    fi
done < file.txt
```

---

Of course, expression `printf "$fmt" ${#items[*]} ${items[-1]}` was used just for demonstration, you can define your own.

---

The above approach outputs(as an example):

```
Number of fields: 3. The last one: cow
Number of fields: 2. The last one: cucumber
Number of fields: 1. The last one: banana
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r column1 column2 column3; do
    if [ -z "$column2" ]; then
        # one column
        : command
    elif [ -z "$column3" ]; then
        # two columns
        : command
    else
        # three columns
        : command
    fi
done < file.txt
```

or

```
while read -r column1 column2 column3; do
    set -- $column1 $column2 $column3
    case $# in
        1)
            : command
        ;;
        2)
            : command
        ;;
        *)
            : command
        ;;
    esac
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hauke Laging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401281/85039) already has a good idea of using evaluation via setting positional parameters and evaluating their number on each iteration. Variation on the theme can be done with use of arrays in `bash` or `ksh` ( which also can be handy in case we do want to keep positional parameters). The below example is for `bash` ( note that for `ksh` or `mksh` you'd use `-A` insead of `-a` in `read`, and of course change `#!` line):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
line_counter=1
while read -r -a arr;
do
    case "${#arr[@]}" in
        1) printf "One column in line %d\n" "$line_counter";;
        2) printf "Two columns in line %d\n" "$line_counter";;
        3) printf "Three columns in line %d\n" "$line_counter";;
        *) printf "More than 3 lines in line %d\n" "$line_counter";;
    esac
    ((line_counter++))
done < input.txt
```

And the output is like so:

```
$ ./eval_columns.sh                                                                                                                                                                  
Three columns in line 1
Two columns in line 2
One column in line 3
```